# Ansible - Unable to decode JSON from response

Tags: ansible, cisco

I'm trying to run the command **show redundant summary** on a cisco Wlan controller (Catalyst 6509-E).

When I use this **aireos_command** from ansible:

```
- name: show redundancy summary
  aireos_command:
    commands: show redundancy summary
  register: wlan_output
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
```

I get following error (ignore deprecation warning):

```
{
  "msg": "Unable to decode JSON from response to exec_command({\"command\": \"show redundancy summary\", \"prompt\": null, \"answer\": null}). Received 'None'.",
  "rc": 1,
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "commands": [
        "show redundancy summary"
      ],
      "provider": {
        "host": null,
        "port": null,
        "username": null,
        "password": null,
        "ssh_keyfile": null,
        "timeout": null
      },
      "match": "all",
      "retries": 10,
      "interval": 1,
      "wait_for": null,
      "host": null,
      "port": null,
      "username": null,
      "password": null,
      "ssh_keyfile": null,
      "timeout": null
    }
  },
  "ansible_facts": {
    "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
  },
  "deprecations": [
    {
      "msg": "Distribution rhel 8.6 on host tcehwa should use /usr/libexec/platform-python, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with prior Ansible releases. A future Ansible release will default to using the discovered platform python for this host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information",
      "version": "2.12"
    }
  ],
  "_ansible_no_log": false,
  "changed": false
}
```

Why do i get **null** as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps installing the Python package `ansible-pylibssh` will help; it seems like the `ansible.module_util.connection.Connection` class isn't happy with Paramiko and the `aireos_command` module.